# Updating SQL database from separate class than CodeBehind - ' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, webforms

ASPX

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" 
         AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestSID.aspx.cs" 
         Inherits="AdminConsole.Pages.TestSID" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="RegisteringAiD" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" 
             Wrap="False" OnTextChanged="RegisteringAiD_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Code behind

```
public partial class TestSID : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public TextBox MakePublicTxt
    {
        get { return this.RegisteringAiD; }
    }

    protected void SubmitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SubmitBtn.Enabled = true;
        App_Code.SQLDBSubmits.SIDSubmit();
        SubmitBtn.Enabled = false;
    }       
}
```

Class to add data to database

```
static class SQLDBSubmits
{
    internal static void SIDSubmit()
    {
        SqlConnection con = SQLDBAccess.DefaultConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TestSID(@RegisteringAiD)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RegisteringAiD", Pages.TestSID.RegisteringAiD.Text);
    }
}
```

Because I'm using a separate class file and not the code-behind to do the SQL update I get this error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0122: 'TestSID.RegisteringAiD' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

I've researched this for days and can't seem figure it out.

Comment: `SIDSubmit` needs a parameter that accepts a `RegisteringAiD`. And that SQL is invalid, it should at the very least have the word `VALUES`, and ideally also the column name `INSERT INTO TestSID (RegisteringAiD) VALUES (@RegisteringAiD);` you also need to open the connection and execute the command, and the connection and command should be in `using` blocks

Comment: ASPX != WebForms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
static class SQLDBSubmits
{
    internal static void SIDSubmit(string aid)
    {
        SqlConnection con = SQLDBAccess.DefaultConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TestSID(@RegisteringAiD)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RegisteringAiD", aid);
    }
}
```

and code behind

```
 App_Code.SQLDBSubmits.SIDSubmit(MakePublicTxt.Text);
```

Comment: Pls, don't forget to accept if it works for you.